# subset reactive dataframe in shiny r

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I current have codes as follows in server page which includes one reactive dataframe containing some datasets. The following is subsetting dataframe to different tabs.

```
  df <- reactive({
    input$Model
    if(input$Model == "Kia Sorento"){            
      kiasorento
    }
    else if(input$Model == "Chevrolet Corvette Stingray"){
      corvette
    }
    else if(input$Model == "MINI Cooper Countryman"){
      countryman
    }
    else if(input$Model == "Subaru Outback"){
      outback
    }
    else if(input$Model == "Porsche 911"){
      porsche
    }
    else if(input$Model == "Mercedes-benz C-Class"){
      C.class
    }
    else if(input$Model == "MINI Cooper"){
      mini
    }
    else if(input$Model == "Jeep Wrangler JK"){
      JK
    }
  })
  # basic info tab
  output$basicInfo <- renderDataTable({
    a1<-which(df[,1]=="Basic Info")+1
    b1<-which(df[,1]=="Body and Dimension")-1
    df %>% slice(a1:b1)
  })
```

it shows an error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

As each dataframe contains mass data, I want to subset the reactive dataframes into matched main panel tabs.

Comment: Try `df() %>% slice(a1:b1)`. To access the value of a `reactive` you have to "call" it like a function using `()`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your advice. I've tried this way but it just keeps loading in the app page and never run properly.

Comment: Any `df` call should be with brackets, so: `a1<-which(df()[,1]=="Basic Info")+1`, `b1<-which(df()[,1]=="Body and Dimension")-1` and `df() %>% slice(a1:b1)`, have you tried this?

Comment: thanks so much for your instructions. it works pretty well now!